# Javascript string reverse for each word

Tags: javascript

I have a string "This should be better", i need to make it as " sihT dlouhs eb retteb"

I am able to split the string but after that i am unable to reverse it.

```
str="This should be better"
str.split(" ")
//["This", "should", "be", "better"]
```

After this how to reverse it as "sihT dlouhs eb retteb"

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
str.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is the same solution I found online but I have also added my own explanation.
The following code will work like:

Input:

```
var str = "Hi Iam Faizan";
```

Output:

```
var outputstr = "iH maI naziaF";
```

Code:

```
var strr = str.split("");//slices all char
var str2 = strr.reverse();// reverse all //char string
var str3 = str2.join("");// merge the reversed characters into one string
var str4 = str3.split(" ");//seperate them with spaces
var str5 = str4.reverse();// reverse the comma separated words back to their original sequence
console.log(str5.join(" "));//finally make them all as one string and separate them with spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with for loop :

```
let str = "This should be better"
let output = "", word = " ";

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) !== " ") {
        word = str.charAt(i) + word
    } else {
        output += word;
        word = " "
    }
}

console.log(output + word);
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i <= len; i++) {
   str[i].split('').reverse().join('');
}
```